# Python exec() updating parameters globally but can't find when inside another function

Tags: python, dictionary, scope, exec, python-2.x

So i'm working in python 2.7.

I'm using this line to execute a series of statements in a dictionary:

```
for key in pipeline: 
    exec(dictionary[key], globals(), globals())
```

This is what the pipeline contains:

```
pipeline = {
    'initializer' : 'initializer()',
    'preprocesser' : 'preprocesser()'
}
```

Here's the two initializer() and preprocesser() functions:

```
def initializer():
    global params 

    data = pd.read_csv(params['dataset'])
    data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    params['data'] = data
    return params 

def preprocesser():
    global params
    print(params.keys())
```

Both of these functions modify a global dictionary called params, here's what it looks like:

```
params = {
                'instruction' : "Predict median house value", 
                'dataset' : './data/housing.csv', 
}
```

For some reason if I print out the dictionary keys of params it'll print the updated keys: the initializer() function is supposed to add a 'data' key to the global params dictionary. But if I print out the list of keys inside the preprocessor() function, I just get ['instruction', 'dataset']. If i print out the keys right after I call the exec function (in a global scope) it correctly prints out ['instruction', 'dataset', 'data]. Why is it updating globally but then I can't access that updated parameter inside the preprocesser() function. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7, dictionary objects do not maintain insertion order. Observe the order that is produced:

```
In [3]: pipeline = {
   ...:     'initializer' : 'initializer()',
   ...:     'preprocesser' : 'preprocesser()'
   ...: }

In [4]: list(pipeline)
Out[4]: ['preprocesser', 'initializer']
```

So pre-processor ran *first*. You don't really need a `dict` here at all, you could just use a list of tuples, or if for some other reason your code requires a dict, then you could keep a list of the keys in the order you want to run things.

But all-in-all, this entire approach is not recommendable. Don't use `exec` here, it gives you no advantages and dynamic code execution has a lot of downsides and it is totally unnecessary in this case. In almost all cases, this one included, it is a clear-cut antipattern.

Also, **don't use mutable global state**. This is yet *another* well-known antipattern. Instead, *pass arguments to functions explicitly*. Here is how I would do this:

```
In [9]: def initializer(params):
   ...:     params['data'] = 42
   ...:     return params
   ...:
   ...: def preprocesser(params):
   ...:     print(params.keys())
   ...:

In [10]: pipeline = [(initializer, (params,)), (preprocesser, (params,))]

In [11]: for func, args in pipeline:
    ...:     func(*args)
    ...:
['instruction', 'data', 'dataset']

In [12]: params
Out[12]:
{'data': 42,
 'dataset': './data/housing.csv',
 'instruction': 'Predict median house value'}
```

Now, generally, it is *also* considered an anti-pattern for functions to mutate their inputs, but this should get you going towards a more sane approach..

Finally, you should avoid using Python 2, it is past its official end of life, it will not longer even get *security updates*, and *[most major third-party libraries](https://python3statement.org/) have also dropped support*, including `pandas` which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone in the future, if your params is global you can also do:

```
reg_pipeline = [initializer,
                preprocesser]


for func in reg_pipeline:
    func(init_params)
```